# Errors while deploying an app on railway-app with poppler

Tags: deployment, nixpkgs

I am using railway.app to deploy my app.

My `nixpacks.toml` is as follows:

```
[phases.name]
  aptPkgs = ["tesseract-ocr", "tesseract-ocr-san", "poppler-utils"]
```

When I run my app, I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 283, in convert_from_bytes
return convert_from_path(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 98, in convert_from_path
page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 488, in pdfinfo_from_path
raise PDFPageCountError(
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
pdfinfo: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /nix/store/c8zdsf7csk8msjb914bhccdhq0ycmqys-gcc-11.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
pdfinfo: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /nix/store/c8zdsf7csk8msjb914bhccdhq0ycmqys-gcc-11.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
pdfinfo: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /nix/store/c8zdsf7csk8msjb914bhccdhq0ycmqys-gcc-11.3.0-lib/lib/libstdc++.so.6)
pdfinfo: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /nix/store/c8zdsf7csk8msjb914bhccdhq0ycmqys-gcc-11.3.0-lib/lib/libgcc_s.so.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my toml file to as follows:

```
[phases.name]
  nixPkgs = ["...", "poppler_utils", "tesseract5"]
```

It seems aptPkgs was using ubuntu style package installation. The nixpkgs were more successful